# Unable to run react-native tutorial due to TransformError with .babelrc

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am unable to get `react-native run-ios` to work on the basic Hello World application that [Facebook ships here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

The error that appears every single time is:

`TransformError: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open <path>/.babelrc`

[image]

When I open `.babelrc`, all it says is:

```
{
"presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

Googling this error shows the following pages:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7906 (I tried `./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh start --reset-cache`, no effect)
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7666 
  (I do not understand the cause and resolution of this error per this thread)
- https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/issues/1266
  (This does not seem to be related to my issue)
- https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/issues/558
  (I attempted to remove .babelrc but it had no effect)

My version is:

`$ react-native --version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.42.3`

I am running OSX 10.12.2, XC 8.3

Can anyone explain the cause, and propose a resolution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a packager running in another window from an old project that I needed to kill. Once I did that, it started working again.